# Variables in Twilio using Node.js and Aritable

Tags: node.js, twilio, airtable

I am new to programming languages and working on a side project using Twilio and Airtable.

I want to send an SMS using variables that I have retrieved from my Airtable Database. I am unable to print variables for the `"to"` number and the `"body"` text such as the first name.

```js
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXX'
const authToken = 'cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'keyXXXXXXXXXX'}).base('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken
);

base('Table_1').select({
    // Selecting the first 3 records in Grid view:
    maxRecords: 1,
    view: "Grid view"
}).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.
        records.forEach(function(record) {
        var name = (record.get('Name'));
    });

client.messages.create({
  from: '+16XXXXXXXX',
  to: '+61XXXXXXXX',
  body: "Hello World My name is," + name
}).then((message) => console.log(message.sid));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` variable is only in scope in your `records.forEach(function(records){})` function. But you need it to hit twilio.   Try something like this.

```
    ...
    records.forEach(function(record) {
    var name = (record.get('Name'));
    client.messages.create({
                from: '+16XXXXXXXX',
                  to: '+61XXXXXXXX',
                body: "Hello World My name is," + name
       }).then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
```

With all its callbcks and nested functions, it can be hard to follow the the flow of control in Javascript programs.

Also, don't forget to put a `.catch()` clause after your `.next()` clause on your `messages.create()` operation.